# How to display a table in Android?

Tags: android, events

I want to display a table in my application, it should contain name, phone no, email as the column names and the table has many rows.

After that I want to capture each item on the onClick listener, please help 
as I am new to this development. I was stopped here, I have implemented a table but unable to capture each item click. Please help with example code.

Comment: In my opinion, you are better off using a ListView and styling the rows to look as you want.  Tables really aren't standard fare in Android, but lists certainly are.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onClickListener` on `TextView` that you are inserting in each column of table.